# Sending a hbs code in app.render and rendering it

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, render

I have a file called content.hbs which looks like something this.

```
<div class="dashboard" class="row" >
{{>topnav}}
Test
{{{graph}}}
</div>
```

Now the {{{graph}}} part is supposed to be a hbc code that plots a pie chart.
Right now the routehandler for content.js looks like this.

```
'use strict';
var querystring  = require('querystring');

module.exports.handle = function(req, res) {
    res.render('content',  {'graph': 'Test'});
}
```

I want to send the hbs code for the pie-chart to content.hbs so that it can replace {{{graph}}}.

Can anyone help me out with this problem?
I thought of sending a graph.hbs file through res.render. But it doesn't seem to be working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you include it just like topnav?

Comment: @Molda That worked. Thanks :)